# Jmeter correlation for values with no left or right boundries

Tags: regex, jmeter

I wanna correlate a alphanumeric **81fe8bfe87576c3ecb22426f8e57847382917acf** value returned from a POST API request as Response which consists of **no left or right boundaries**, I am using **^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$** as regex expression which is a correct regex expression with Jmeter RegExp Tester, but unable to extract the alphanumeric value from the response and store in a variable as determined by the logs using Regular Expression Extractor.

[image: JmeterRegex]

But, Values returned by the logs shows unable to extract alphanumeric value using Regular Expression Extractor.

[image: JmeterLog]

Here is my Regular Expression Extractor to extract the alphanumeric value

[image: JmeterRegularExpressionExtractor]

I already have tried out all the Fields to check options available, nothing works. I am not sure , exactly why is it not working as the regex expression **^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$** is correct, maybe it's related to **empty or no left and right boundaries**.

Would really appreciate any resolution provided.

Comment: It seems you just need to use `$0$` template (you have `$1$` now)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "empty or no left and right boundaries"? Does `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` with `$0$` template work as expected? Do you want ``\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{42}\b``?

Comment: Thank You @WiktorStribiżew. Replacing the `$1` with `$0$` worked. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` regex contains no capturing groups, but your template, `$1$`, retrieves Group 1 value from the match. Since the match has no Group 1, the value is not found.

There are two solutions:

1. Replace your `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` with `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` and keep on using `$1$` template.
2. Replace `$1$` with `$0$` so as to access the whole match value, Group 0, rather than Group 1 (that is missing in the original regex).

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to surround your regular expression with parentheses in order to have a capture group, see [Meta Characters](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) chapter of JMeter User Manual for more information
2. Given you need to extract only alphanumeric characters you can simplify your regular expression to just `(\w+)`
3. **Given you need to get the full response you can just use Boundary Extractor and leave both boundaries blank - JMeter will store the whole response into a JMeter Variable (it will work for [JMeter 5.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-jmeter-5.2/) or higher, see [JMeter Bug 63775](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63775) for details**
4. If you need to store the whole response into a JMeter Variable and want to use Regular Expression Extractor for this the relevant regular expression would be `(?s)(^.*)`

Comment: Please note that 1) Point 1 is covered in my answer, 2) `\w` does not only match alphanumeric chars, `\w` also matches an underscore, a punctuation character, 3) `(?s)(^.*)` is OK to match any (even empty) string, but it is considered "bad regex style" to capture zero-width assertions, so `(?s)^(.*)` would be a "prettier" regex. However, this is very preferential, and certainly does not affect the overall results.